# why did catkin_make never output the execuatble file again after I executed catkin_make_isolated command to compile code

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin-make-isolated

The system is ROS noetic,Ubuntu 20.04.06.  Once I executed the "catkin_make_isolated" command to compile my ROS1 workspace. After did it I found the catkin_make command can never output the executable file again. The compile process has no any error messages, but the executable file in devel/lib directory can not be produced again. I feel the cmake process is correct, but the make process has some problem maybe. My questions is: how can I restore to use the catkin_make instead if catkin_make_isolated to compile the ROS1 code again?

Comment: As a comment on your question. Please consider in your next question working to reduce the problem down to a minimal example which will make it easier for you and others who might want to help you to understand and solve your problem. My answer below is a guess based on the broad themes outline in your question. But I cannot be completely confident in if it will solve your problem without more information to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use catkin_make_isolated it sets up the workspace and invokes CMake to use isolated installation directories. These parameters are cached by CMake in various places such as the CMakeCache.txt files and other generated intermediate files.

If you want to switch between building an isolated workspace and a merged workspace you should clean all the build artifacts and rebuild your workspace to make sure that all the references use the preferred system.

I'll note that the merged workspace will only work for catkin packages. And will not work for pure CMake packages that catkin_make_isolated can support, and is generally recommended now.

Comment: I see. I have cleaned the build and devel directory files in desktop window (not in terminal) and  rebuilt before, but that is not enough. After read your answer I think maybe there are some  CMake files in other directories, or some hidden files I didn't clean. Or maybe I should do catkin_init_workspace. But it is troublesome and not worth. So I will use the better catkin_make_isolated in stead of catkin_make in future. Thank you.

Comment: Please take a moment to accept this answer so others know it's resolved for you.